# Flutter Riverpod design pattern (inhibit garbage collection)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, dart-pub, riverpod

I've written a Swift/IOS package to externalize and standardize all of my Social/Federated/Firebase authentication boilerplate (both SDK's and UI).  I've taken it upon myself to port this to Flutter as a learning exercise ... but to also allow custom UI to be passed-in via config.

Since I'm new to Flutter & Riverpod, I'm afraid I'm making some serious mistake & want to get feedback from you experts before I go too deep.

The package is called "Social Login Helper" or SLH, and this is the public API I desire:

```
  runApp(
    slh.authStateBuilder(
      builder: (authStatus) {
        switch (authStatus.stage) {
          case SlhResultStage.initializing:
            return SplashScreen();
          case SlhResultStage.unauthenticated:
            // using Riverpod and Nav 2.0
            return slh.authFlowUi;
          case SlhResultStage.authenticated:
            return ExampleApp(appKey, authStatus, slh.logoutCallback);
          case SlhResultStage.wantsAnnonOnlyFeatures:
            return ExampleApp(appKey, null, slh.startAuthCallback);
          case SlhResultStage.excessiveFailures:  // restart the app
            return TotalFailure();
        }
      },
    ),
  );
```

As you can see from the above, the State/Stream builder at root must never be garbage collected or purged.  I'm unclear if and when Riverpod will dispose my provider, or if Dart itself will collect objects that must remain immortal.  I'm also unsure whether to use a StreamProvider or a State provider??

As you can see below, I've created an intentional memory-leak (deadlock) to guard me.  I'm sure it's an anti-pattern, but being novice, I'm not sure how else to guarantee immortality.

All guidance and explicit feedback would be most welcome.

```
class LivingAuthState extends StateNotifier<SlhResultStage> {
  // create deadly embrace to prevent this from ever being collected
  _Unpurgeable _up;
  LivingAuthState() : super(SlhResultStage.initializing) {
    //
    final StreamProvider<SlhResultStage> rssp =
        StreamProvider<SlhResultStage>((ref) {
      return this.stream.asBroadcastStream();
    });

    _up = _Unpurgeable(this, rssp);

    // how do I keep rssp from ever being collected??
  }
  StreamProvider<SlhResultStage> get authStatusStream => _up.rssp;

  void logout() {
    this.state = SlhResultStage.unauthenticated;
  }

  void restartLogin() {
    this.state = SlhResultStage.unauthenticated;
  }
}

class _Unpurgeable {
  final LivingAuthState _aliveState;
  final StreamProvider<SlhResultStage> rssp;
  _Unpurgeable(this._aliveState, this.rssp);
}
```

One improvement I'd like to see in the Riverpod documentation is clarity on HOW LONG a provider will live, WITHOUT an active listener, before it will self-dispose / garbage-collect.

Ah, it looks like I can subclass AlwaysAliveProviderBase() to achieve the same goal ... I'll experiment with this.

Answer (score 1):

Move your provider final to the top level. Riverpod providers are top-level final variables.

Also remember to wrap your app in the riverpod provider.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Providers are normally top-level, but in this case, my provider only has one use case ... to convert it's parent StateNotifier into a StreamProvider<SlhResultStage> ... which gives me data

See this line above:
  StreamProvider<SlhResultStage> get authStatusStream => _up.rssp;
In that case, is there any reason to expose it more widely??


The wrapping in this case, is done inside of slh.authFlowUi  because I can't be certain that my host environment will be using Riverpods and I don't want to force that.

please let me know if any of this sounds like a mistake.

Comment: See the documentation for the [ProviderScope](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/all/ProviderScope-class.html). According to the documentation your providers are disposed when the ProviderScope widget is disposed and it's ProviderContainer is disposed with it. Therefore your providers are scoped to their parent ProviderScope.